# How to delete records from a Firebase database when are existing multiple childs with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a relative simple Firebase database which looks like this:
[image]

If i want to delete the `Rooms` node bases on the `message`, i know how to do it but how can i delete the `Room1` node, when i only know the `userName`? When i'm using this code, nothing happens.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms");
Query deleteQuery = databaseReference.child("Room1").child("userModel").orderByChild("userName").equalTo("Alex");
    deleteQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ds.getRef().removeValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: you say that you want to delete `Rooms` node bases on `message`, but in your code, you delete based on `userName` that is `Alex`. So which one you want to do?

Comment: As i said, i know how to delete `Room1` node based on `message`. What i do not know, is how to delete `Room1` node, based on the `userName`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think @variousbulk 's answer is the best solution if you don't want to remodel your database. Wait for their reply

Comment: Ok, i'll wait for his answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If remodeling database is not an option, then the simplest way is to loop through `Rooms` node.

```
String username = "Alex";
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot room : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            boolean containUsername = false;
            for (DataSnapshot roomChild : room.getChildren()) {
                if (roomChild.child("userModel/userName").getValue(String.class).equals(username)) {
                    containUsername = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (containUsername)
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rooms/" + room.getKey()).removeValue();
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Note: I haven't check if `roomChild.child("userModel/userName")` can be used. If it produces error, change it with `roomChild.child("userModel").child("userName")`

Comment: Thanks koceeng but as it is, i cannot user the removeValue() method on the variable `room`. Error is: `cannot resolve method removeValue()`.

Comment: my bad, try change it to `room.getRef().removeValue();`

Comment: Same problem. After `getRef` i cannot use `removeValue()` method :|

Comment: After `room.getKey())` there must a dot, and in stead of `child("userModel/userName")` it must be `child("userModel/username")`, but still not working. I'm trying to find another way and i think the best way is to redesign my database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better practice to return the ID using the `getID()` method and delete based on that.